# How can we add site URL, item id and library to SharePoint list button using JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, json-formatting, column-formatting

How can we add site URL, item id and library to SharePoint list button using JSON?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "   Start Approval",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"v1/7e49e305-c311-47e2-aaa8-69644acb846b/d306f2cb-760c-4db7-b36c-9df91e1ef71f\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=@currentWeb +'https://akzonobel.sharepoint.com/teams/MSTest/PowerApps/Bulletins_SEEMEA/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx=' + [$Library]"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "#008082",
    "color": "white",
    "border-radius": "0 15px",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share more details about your requirements? Are you trying to add site URL of current site where you are adding JSON or you have any column in the library/list which stores the site URL? same question for library name and item ID, are you trying to add current library name and item ID or do you have columns which stores this information?

Comment: Also, are you trying to run the Power automate flow or show some hyperlink using column formatting? The JSON you used is trying to have both and is invalid JSON as per SharePoint JSON formatting.

Comment: yes actually i have created one library in which i have added button in column so the scenario is in that jason formatte button i have to add site url and library and id of the document how can i add that

Comment: `@currentWeb` will give you the URL of the site, `[$ID]` will give you the list item Id. Unfortunately, there is nothing to retrieve the library name or library id within list formatting.